# Modelling Low Poly Hair style

Tags: modeling, mesh, hair, polycount

My question here is not a technical issue with Blender, rather it is asking as to whether anyone is able to provide me with suggestions for a modelling technique/procedure.

I'm interested in learning to model low poly hair styles created as a ***single mesh***. The type of hair style I am trying to model are those from RPG video games.

I have come across a fair few youtube tutorials on how to model hair using the 'curves and circles' method. The issue here is that each lock of hair is separated from one another rather than as a single mesh I'll give you an example. 
[image]
The image above comes from a model which was not modelled by me as it came from a video game. But for educational purposes I will show it here,

What I want to highlight in this model is that it demonstrates a 3D model of hair that looks like it exists as a single continuous mesh. I know this because when I am in edit mode, I can select a vertex on the model and when I hit (ctrl+L); just about the entire model lights up which means all of the vertices were connected to each other in some way. In other words, the Author of this model was able to achieve low poly hair using a single mesh.

Now below is a hair mesh that I modelled which is not necessarily low poly. 
[image]
As you can see I modelled each of the locks of hair separately. But they are not still a single 'mesh' if that makes any sense. Its not as simple as selecting all the meshes in Object mode and using CTRL+J since that only joins the objects together but does not make them a single continuous mesh when I enter edit mode.

I tried to model the same hair using the 'Curve and circle' method, and I still ran into this problem as I could only model one lock of hair per object at a time which means each lock of hair would have to be modelled as separate objects.

In addition I have tried the Boolean modifier to try and artificially 'unite' each of the locks of hair, but there were too many stray vertices and the resulting mesh did not provide the result that I was after.

I believe that fundamentally trying to model the hairstyle by modelling each of the locks of hair separately is not the way to go. Could the original author have probably made the model by extrusion?

I think this is mainly a question for persons who have experience with modelling low poly character models for video games. I'd be delighted if anyone can share with me their thoughts and suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick idea to try: You could try applying a remesh modifier (with low quality settings) on the boolean version you made. The result may be improved by manual pushing around of some vertices...

Comment: Another more work intensive method (which i personally prefer) would be manual retopology of your mesh. Here you would start with one point extrude it and snap it to a mesh face (with the magnet function)... then repeat this, make triangles and then manually make faces inbetween with "F"

Comment: It's not necessarily the best idea to have the hair as a continuous mesh for various reasons. 1) being polycount. I was quite obsessed with continuous meshes myself, until I figured out that they don't give any advantage. 2) being the fact that you are technically going to create separate meshes anyway, once you UV-unwrap the hair piece. However, there's absolutely nothing wrong with creating all the pieces separately then join them (Ctrl+J) into a single (non-continuous) mesh.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I got it all worked out